# Allow match - special characters should only appear once in a row

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that cleans string of all unwanted characters.

Allowed characters (matches) are `A-Z` `a-z` `0-9` `-` and `/`

What i have so far works like it should:

```
$step2 = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\/]/', '', $step1);
```

The only thing i cannot achieve is that `-` should appear only once in a row.

EDIT: Multiple instances of `-` should be replaced with just one.

Comment: What should happen if `-` appears more than once in a row? Do you mean to replace `---` with `-`, for example, or should the regex fail, or what?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the multiple instances should be replaced with just one, like stated, - is otherwise an allowed character.

Comment: Post your sample input and output and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it in a single regular expression would be to capture the `-` in a repeated group (which may or may not exist), alternating with your other negated character set. Replace with the first captured group (which will be `-` if `-` was matched, and the empty string otherwise).

Also note that `0-9` simplifies to `\d`, which is a bit nicer to read. In addition, repeating the negated character set will make the operation a bit more efficient - that way, if there are multiple characters to be replaced in a row, only *one* replacement has to occur there, rather than a replacement for each character.

```
$step1 = "$$$ foobar --- 123 --- barbaz -$-";
$step2 = preg_replace('/(?:(-)|[^A-Za-z\d\/-])+/', '$1', $step1);
```

Output:

```
foobar-123-barbaz-
```

Comment: This is the better answer +1.  I couldn't imagine a way to do this with a single replacement.  Good trick replacing with the empty capture group for non dash characters +1.

Comment: Great explanation. What about cases when another unallowed character is between two `-`, for example `-$-`. In that case, the double `-` stays in the output string after the unallowed one is removed. Only the sequential use of two `preg_replace`s solves the problem in this example.

Comment: @BikerJohn Ah, didn't think about that possibility, but it's a simple tweak, alternate between the `-` and the other characters inside a repeated non-capturing group.

Comment: I have one more question. What if I wanted to add another character using the same rules like we did for `-`? For example `/`.

Comment: @BikerJohn Tricky, while keeping the character set written just once in the RE. `([-\/])?\1*(?:[^a-z\d\/-]*\1*)+` works but matches zero-length strings as well. There's probably a nicer way while keeping the RE DRY but I can't figure it out at the moment. https://regex101.com/r/uIfcpY/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove all special characters, while allowing at most a single hyphen, then try the following:

```
$step2 = preg_replace('/[-]+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\/]/', '', $step1));
```

This just does a separate second replacement to collapse multiple dash occurrences (e.g. `----`) into a single dash.

Comment: Great, i think you forgot to include `-` in the basic match scheme `^A-Za-z0-9\/`, otherwise all of them will be deleted before moving to second `preg_replace`. When this is added, it solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to pass an array with patterns and replacements to [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

The first pattern `[^A-Za-z0-9/-]` will match what is not in the character class and replace that with an empty string. The second pattern will match 2+ times a `-` and replace that with a single `-`.

```
$step1 = "This is a --- test with-----a dash-.";
$step2 = preg_replace(array('~[^A-Za-z0-9/-]~','~-{2,}~'), array('', '-'), $step1);
echo $step2; // Thisisa-testwith-adash-
```

Comment: Also an interesting example worth remembering.